# React - show menu when clicking on just one item from iterating item

Tags: reactjs

I'm having problem with sliding menu in just one item.

When I click on the config button every item shows menu. I tried to figure out something by passing props `{mail.id}` but I'm afraid I don't understand this.

I would like to have sliding menu just in one item -- the clicked one.

This is `ConfigButton`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Menu.css';

class ConfigButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="configButton"
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        <i className="configButtonIcon fas fa-cog"></i>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default ConfigButton;
```

And this is the `Component` which renders:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Menu from './Menu';
import ConfigButton from './ConfigButton';

const API = myAPI;

const navLinkStyle = {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: '#123e57'
};

class Emails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      visible: false,
      mails: []
    };

    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseDown(e) {
    this.toggleMenu();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(API)
      .then(response => {
        const mails = response.data;
        this.setState({ mails });
      })       
  }

  truncate = (text, chars = 140) =>
    text.length < chars ? text : (text.slice(0, chars) + '...')

  render() {

    let mails = this.state.mails;
    console.log(mails);

    mails = mails.map(mail => {
      return (
        <div key={mail.id}>
          <div className='mail'>

            {
              !mails.displayed
              ? <i className="notDisplayed fas fa-circle"></i>
              : <i className="displayed far fa-circle"></i>
            }

            <HashRouter>
              <NavLink
                to={`/openemail/${mail.id}`}
                style={navLinkStyle}
              >
                <ul className='ulMailWrap'>
                  <div className='mailHeader'>
                    <li>{mail.sender}</li>
                    <li>{mail.created}</li>
                  </div>
                  <li>{mail.subject}</li>             
                  <li>{this.truncate(mail.message)}</li>
                </ul>
              </NavLink>
            </HashRouter>

            <ConfigButton onClick={this.handleMouseDown} />
            <Menu handleMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
              menuVisibility={this.state.visible}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )   
    });

    return (
       <div>
         { mails }
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Emails;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function that will send a different parameter to the handler, depending on value of each element in the array.

Do something like this:

```
...
<div key={mail.id} onClick={() => this.handleOpenMenu(mail.id)}>
...
```

Then at the handler:

```
handleOpenMenu = id => {
  // do different stuffs on the id you get here 
  this.setState({ visibleMenuId: id });
}
```

And then change the props you are passing to your menu component:

```
<Menu menuVisibility={this.state.visibleMenuId === mail.id} />
```

Comment: Thanks,

the point is that the sliding menu is the same for every item. For example on of the menu's button is delete option. And if I click on the delete button I would like to delete only clicked item, not everyone.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my comment is probably quite misleading. Yes, the point is you do different things based on the `id` you get, even if the displayed menu is the same. You can delete the mail that has that `id`.

Comment: Yes, but delete option is not the only one. I used your solultion previously but it won't do the stuff. Maybe some advice where to look for the solution? Couse sliding menu still shows on every item.

Comment: Are you saying that `<Menu>` is always shown for every item even if only one of them is clicked? See my updated answer.

Comment: If someone is interested in resolve this problem I did it with help of Jackyef. I added his solution - thank you Jackyef - and also added this code to <Menu /> component:

<Menu handleMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                              menuVisibility={
                                mail.id === this.state.id
                                ? this.state.visible
                                : false
                              }
                        />

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. Would you mind accepting the answer so that this question can be closed?

Comment: @thanks Jackyef.. this is the best solution i found for my scenario from many solutions provided on other blogs